# localStorage is not defined in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, local-storage

I had trouble using Local Storage in Next JS, and sometimes Windows, and sometimes Local Storage is not defined.
I want to keep the values for Front, not on the server

If you have an example or solution, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Next.js, components are rendered server-side. `localStorage` - or the `window` - are not available until [rendered in a browser](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/19911#discussioncomment-148457).

You can use `useEffect` or a conditional that checks if the window is defined: `const clientSide = typeof window !== 'undefined'`